# how to handle dynamic components with vuejs and require.ensure

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2, vue.js, webpack-2

I have a concept that I'm trying to find the best way to approach. I'm using VueJS and webpack 2. My scenario is I want to have a list of components that I want to load on demand when the user clicks an item. For example, I'd have a list of 5 components (YouTube, Facebook, Twitter, Pandora, Spotify) in an array. I'd use v-for to repeat the list using LI elements.

```
<li v-for="component in components" v-on:click="openApp">{{component.name}}</li>
```

I want for the user to click on an li and run a method on my VueJS instance. Hence the v-on:click. The method for openApp would look as follows:

```
openApp() {
    require.ensure(["./components/myComponent.vue"], function(){})
}
```

The issue I'm having is I can't dynamically pass a name to the require.ensure as follows.

```
openApp() {
    let name = "myComponent";
    require.ensure(["./components/" + name + ".vue"], function(){})
}
```

I understand why I can't do this. However, this presents me with a bit of an architectural issue. For each item I'll have to add a separate function that basically does the same thing every time. This isn't such a bit deal with 5 items, but if I hit 50, 100, 1000 items the it's going to get ugly. My question is, what would be the best way to approach this? Should I bite the bullet and hardcode each method with a redundant require.ensure? Or is that a more dynamic approach to this I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

`webpack` should be able to create a new chunk with the modules mentioned in the first argument to `require.ensure`. It does support having dynamically discovered modules, e.g.:

`require.ensure(["./components/" + name + ".vue"], function(){})`

would create a chunk with all modules from `./components/*.vue` location - i.e. during the build it will scan the directory and add all `*.vue` files.

However, if at runtime you'd try to `require` a module that did not exist during build time, it will fail.

While technically you would be able to create a **lot** of components in a chunk, probably you'd redesign your application to have a single component that behaves differently based on inputs.